# Installing TeX: MacOS terminal launch with -bash: /Applications/MiKTeX: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, latex

I have tried a few times using TeX on my MacOS through installing MiKTeX console, including changing environmental variables. However, every time I opens terminal, it always automatically shows:

`-bash: /Applications/MiKTeX: No such file or directory`.

Command`echo $PATH` returns `/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/user/bin`

Comment: For mac I would recommend to use mactex or simply normal texlive instead of miktex.

Comment: That said -- Is there anything in your `.bashrc`, `.profile` or `.bash_profile` that is related to tex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is now solved after I uninstalled MiKTeX and deleted that in `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/user/bin;/Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin/cjklatex
```